# How can i self delete electron app on close?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I tried to spawn bat file cmd, which kill app and remove all files in it directory. But i have problem - some files dont remove, because some of them are busy with some another process.maybe there is an easier way.

electron.js:

```js
spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'path\\help.bat'], { detached: true, stdio: 'ignore' })
```

help.bat

```sh
timeout /t 10 >nul   taskkill /T /F /IM "my.exe"   rmdir /S /Q current_dir_path
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using for removing the files and also what all files are not getting removed?

Comment: this at electron:  
`spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'path\\help.bat'], { detached: true, stdio: 'ignore' })`  
and help.bat:  
`timeout /t 10 >nul  
taskkill /T /F /IM "my.exe"  
rmdir /S /Q current_dir_path`